# adding a custom field to netsuite sales order api restlet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am needing to add a custom field called Purchase Order# to my netsuite api the json I currently use is formatted as follows:

```
{"entity":"1117","recordtype":"salesorder","item":[{"item":"311","amount":"1234"},{"item":"311","amount":"1234"}]}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Netsuite's built in field for po number is otherrefnum. Your question needs a lot more information to be answerable.  -- see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if using the json format. How do I add say a purchase order numbered 1234 into the sales order. I apologize.

Comment: If you are doing Netsuite work you should have access to an account. The help there explains the various ways to interact with Netsuite. You need to explain what you are trying to do including the the type of script, the source of the information, the result you are trying to achieve etc. Netsuite has script examples (admittedly not comprehensive) covering most of the basics which can be used to get you started.

Comment: @bknights thanks if it was that simple. the netsuite postman examples don't cover that topic at all. Which is literally all you get from netsuite in that case. So I ask again, in terms of adding an address to a sales order that's being created via rest api. How do you go about it.

Comment: You  need to specify  if you are using   suitetalk or suitescript (1.0,2.0,2.1)   first you should have created the custom field in saleorder then in suitecript  asign the value

Comment: @wozzarvl suitscript 2.0. the po# should be whatever it says is standard. they just made it mandatory.